# Is there an equivalent to imagecolorset for GD from PHP in Perl?

Tags: perl, gd

I have a transparent image and I would like to change it's color. In PHP this was done by using imagecolorset but I have read through CPAN's doc on GD and I am unable to comprehend how to do it in Perl. (Using fill does not preserve the transparency)

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The nearest equivalent would seem to be [`colorAllocate`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/GD#Color_Control).

Comment: Presumably in conjunction with `$image->transparent($colorIndex)`.